# Azure disk replication across VMs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, replication, azure-disk

In Azure, is it possible to have master VM that writes to a disk which has read-only slave replicas on other VMs?

Our app needs to download ~100GB of files when scaling to a new VM. This is loaded slowly from an external provider but we want to make it available quickly when we scale out more VMs.

Comment: You can use Azure storage to store the data. Maybe you also can make the VM into an image.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but... every blob has snapshot ability (and you can share snapshot links - they are read-only). There is no actual disk replication feature; you'd have to do that yourself. In any event: this type of question should be posted to ServerFault, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do streaming replication (which I think is what you're asking for), or read only slave through the Azure service without implementing this yourself over network or through a relational database management system.

As of this writing, one disk cannot be connected to multiple Azure VMs (See [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/faq-for-disks) for Managed Disks. One option would be to create a snapshot of the disk, and create a new disk from the snapshot. You could automate this via the Azure Managed Disk Service API (eg: an Azure Powershell script), and it would have to happen on a VM that isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is same and doesn't change per new VM created then you can have it stored on the Azure File Storage Standard/ Premium. Then have Azure File storage attached to every new VM whenever it is created. snapshot disk will make it pretty complex. Azure Files Storage is good choice in this scenario.